# MySQL - MOD() return 1 instead of 0

Tags: mysql, modulo

I have the following MySQL code that according to me should return 0:

```
mod(    mod((180 / (30.4166666667 * 24 * 60)),1) * 30.4166666667,1) * 24 as HoursWorked 
  => return 3.000

mod(mod(mod((180 / (30.4166666667 * 24 * 60)),1) * 30.4166666667,1) * 24,1) as ModHoursWorked 
  => return 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

the division must be floored

```
select mod(mod(mod(( floor(180 / (30.4166666667 * 24 * 60)) ),1) * 30.4166666667,1) * 24,1) ;
```

Comment: Now this does not work:
select mod(mod(mod(floor(190 / (30.4166666667 * 24 * 60)), 1) * 30.4166666667, 1) * 24, 1) as ModHoursWorked => return 0.000 in stead of 0.1666666..

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, maybe will help in elaborate this query

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SELECT truncate(mod(mod(mod((180 / (30.4166666667 * 24 * 60)),1) * 30.4166666667, 1) * 24, 1), 0) AS ModHoursWorked; => return 0
```